# Error in posting json data to a URL

Tags: java, json, rest, url

I am trying to push json data it is working with following code but, not able to get required result when i am sending json data directly, means if replace ##line1 by String input =jsonString;

my json String constructed as:

```
ArrayList <ContactData> documents;
Gson g = new Gson();
String jsonString = g.toJson(documents);
```

then passing json string to my method

```
private void pushDataToClientURL(String clientURL, String jsonString)
        {
            try {

                log.debug("starting pushing data to Client URL");

                URL targetUrl = new URL(clientURL);

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
                httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                OutputStream outputStream = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
            ##line1 String input ="{\"statusCode\":1,\"type\":\"Liam\",\"age\":22,\"value\":\"Marco\"}";

                outputStream.write(input.getBytes());
                outputStream.flush();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                            + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
                }

                BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (httpConnection.getInputStream())));

                String output;

                log.debug("Output from Server:\n");

                while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

                httpConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
```

This is the code for my Rest Service

```
@POST
        @Path("/dataPosting")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response consumeJSON(ContactData bean){

            String result = bean.toString();

            return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
        }

    Getting error


Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
    at com.rest.test.profiling.ProfilingDataPushJOB.pushDataToClientURL(ProfilingDataPushJOB.java:127)
    at com.rest.test.profiling.ProfilingDataPushJOB.run(ProfilingDataPushJOB.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If this would have URL problem, This would have not work with the written code that i pasted here, it is not only working when i am replacing ##line1 assigned with json string means without "\" character in my string

Comment: Did you try with `StringEntity`? and added `setContentType("application/json")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your JSON string to string entity and setEntity for http post request.
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonString);

Comment: how and where to set in above code, could u plz tel